# Symmetrization in Proof of Hoeffding's Lemma

Tags: probability-inequalities, bounds, symmetry, hoeffdings-inequality

This alternative proof of a slightly weaker version of Hoeffding's Lemma features in Stanford's CS229 course notes. What's notable about this proof is its use of *symmetrization*. However, I find this part of the proof to be very unclear. The proof is on page 7 of this pdf: http://cs229.stanford.edu/extra-notes/hoeffding.pdf

Namely, the proof claims that $Z - Z'$ is symmetric around the origin, and therefore a random sign variable $S(Z - Z')$ will have exactly the same distribution as $Z-Z'$. I can see that the density of $Z - Z'$ will be symmetric around $0$, but how does $S =\text{sign}(Z -Z')$ have "exactly the same distribution"?

Secondly, assuming $S$ has the same distribution as $Z - Z'$, why is the following statement implied?
$$
\mathbb{E}_{Z,Z'}[\exp(\lambda(Z-Z'))] = \mathbb{E}_{Z,Z',S}[\exp(\lambda S(Z-Z'))]
$$

Comment: You misinterpret the statement: the claim is that the *product* of $S$ and $Z-Z^\prime$ has the same distribution as $Z-Z^\prime.$ (This is true only with the additional assumptions that $S$ has equal chances of both signs and is independent of $Z,$ btw.)  Since the values of $S$ are in $\{-1,1\},$ there are very few random variables $Z$ for which $S$ and $Z-Z^\prime$ can possibly have the same distribution! The answer to your second question is immediate once you fix this misinterpretation.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense! Thank you.